# Fetching data from firebase does not works with Angular Universal

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, angularfire, angular-universal

- I made an Angular 11 project from scratch (with router).
- I installed AngularFire with : ng add @angular/fire
- I have added firebase config in environments
- I installed Angular Universal with : ng add @nguniversal/express-engine
- I have created a new component "Pages" with : ng g c pages
- I imported AngularFireModule and PagesComponent in app.module.ts :

  ```
  import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
  import { AngularFireModule } from '@angular/fire';
  import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
  import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';
  import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
  import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
  import { PagesComponent } from './pages/pages.component';

  @NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    PagesComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule.withServerTransition({ appId: 'serverApp' }),
    AppRoutingModule,
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebase)
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
  })
  export class AppModule { }
  ```

Then i have created a PagesResolver :

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireDatabase } from '@angular/fire/database';
import { Resolve } from '@angular/router';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map, take } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class PagesResolver implements Resolve<any> {

  constructor(
    private db: AngularFireDatabase
  ) { }

  resolve(): Observable<any> {
    return this.db.list('/pages').snapshotChanges().pipe(
      map((uploadData) => {
        const newUploadData = uploadData.map(c => ({ key: c.payload.key, ...c.payload.val() as any }));
        console.log(newUploadData)
        return newUploadData;
      }),
      take(1)
    );
  }
}
```

Then i have configured my app-routing.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { PagesResolver } from './pages.resolver';
import { PagesComponent } from './pages/pages.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: PagesComponent,
    resolve: { pages: PagesResolver }
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {
    initialNavigation: 'enabled'
})],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Now, If i run 'ng serve', everything is fine. My data is well loaded from resolver.
But if i run 'npm run prerender', it starts to prerender and at the end it falls in infinite loop without ending the prerendering task.
If i run 'npm run dev:ssr', the page falls in infinite loop loading without timeout.

What did i miss please ? How can i have access to my firebase database with ssr ?

Here is a repo: https://github.com/rebeb74/test-universal

Comment: Hi, have you found a solution to this issue?